# How to set queue max length for activemq

Tags: java, queue, activemq-classic, configure

I'm wondering if I can configure a queue's max length on activemq, so that when the queue's length touch the limit, the enqueue operation will failed or throw exceptions. is anybody know about this question? any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at Producer Flow Control http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html

It limits your queue on the amount of memory the queue takes so its not a numbers of messages approach but a memory sizing approach.  You can have an exception thrown back to the client when the broker reaches its max resources limit.